# Git - How to enable Git showing folder and file status' in explorer?

Tags: git

So I started working seriously with Git only at the beginning of this week. While I am using Git in college, I clone my repository down and I am able to see a little green circle with a tick next to my project folder indicating that everything is up to date and no changes have been made. When I make changes the little circle changes red indicating that changes have been made. Here is an example image of this:

[Git Status Overlays for Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxMCn.png)

When I am at home working with Git, I do not see this status' on explorer at all and I was wondering how I can get this on my computer?

Hope it's not a silly question, just can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 4):

You probably have [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) installed on your college computer. It is an Explorer Shell extension that lets you manage your Git repository from Explorer. It adds icon overlays, among other features.

Comment: Much appreciated! Didn't know that was a feature provided by separate software. I was just above to go through Git installation process again.

Comment: @LiliamF. You're welcome. :) If this answers your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: is there any linux version of it?

Comment: @HakanUlusoy I'm not sure - I haven't looked since I don't typically do development in a Linux desktop envrionment.

Answer (score -2):

check `www.mygitexplorer.com` for folder and file status in git.